# Rails Module/Folder Naming Convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with a module name and the folder structure.

I have a model defined as

```
module API
  module RESTv2
    class User
    end
  end
end
```

The folder structure looks like

```
models/api/restv2/user.rb
```

When trying to access the class, I get an uninitialized constant error.  However, if I change the module name to REST and the folder to /rest, I don't get the error.

I assume the problem has to do with the naming of the folder, and I've tried all different combos of /rest_v_2, /rest_v2, /restv_2, etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By Rails convention, you've named your module incorrectly. `RESTv2` should be `RestV2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rails [uses](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L451) the 'underscore' method on a module or class name to try and figure out what file to load when it comes across a constant it doesn't know yet. When you run your module through this method, it doesn't seem to give the most intuitive result:

```
"RESTv2".underscore
# => "res_tv2"
```

I'm not sure why underscore makes this choice, but I bet renaming your module dir to the above would fix your issue (though I think I'd prefer just renaming it to "RestV2 or RESTV2 so the directory name is sane).

Comment: This actually makes perfect sense, it's the string `RESTv2` that doesn't follow convention. The assumption is that the first word is some kind of acronym like "PIN", and the second word is an uppercase word like "Importer": `PINImporter` => `pin_importer`, `UUIDGenerator` => `uuid_generator`, `AESCracker` => `aes_cracker`, `RESTv2` => `res_tv2`, etc etc. In all cases of CamelCase conversion, It's not "CamelC ase", it's "Camel Case". The space is injected *before* the final uppercase letter, not after.

Comment: I suspect the case of "v" is what causes the word break before the "T".

Comment: If you're being an exceptional noob like me today, make sure you're using `rails console` instead of just `irb`

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to configure Rails to autoload in the subdirectories of the app/model directory. Put this in your config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

Then you should be able to autoload those files.

Also, your likely filename will have to be app/model/api/res_tv2/user.rb, as Rails uses String.underscore to determine the filename. I'd just call it API::V2::User to avoid headaches, unless you have more than one type of API.